# AndroidChromecastSDK (Xamarin Bindings) : Getting the RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaStatus always return null

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, google-play-services, chromecast

I'm developping a custom sender application for chromecast in C# using Xamarin. At this point, I can send `MediaInfo` to the receiver app and play a song correctly on my TV. The problem I have is when I try to stop the `RemoteMediaPlayer`.

Calling `Stop()` on the player returns a `Java.Lang.IllegalStateException : No current media session` exception. This is weird since I can hear the music playing, so there must be an active media session...

Also, I tried setting the `OnStatusUpdatedListener` (`AndroidMediaPlayer` inherits from `RemoteMediaPlayer`) like this

```
mediaPlayer = new AndroidMediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.SetOnStatusUpdatedListener(new AndroidMediaPlayerOnStatusUpdated(this, mediaPlayer));
```

with a custom implementation of the Interface

```
internal class AndroidMediaPlayerOnStatusUpdated: Java.Lang.Object, RemoteMediaPlayer.IOnStatusUpdatedListener {
    private readonly AndroidChromecastController controller;
    private readonly RemoteMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    public AndroidMediaPlayerOnStatusUpdated(AndroidChromecastController aController, RemoteMediaPlayer aMediaPlayer) {
        controller = aController;
        mediaPlayer = aMediaPlayer;
    }

    public void OnStatusUpdated()
    {
        var status = mediaPlayer.MediaStatus;
        switch (status.PlayerState)
        {
            case MediaStatus.PlayerStateBuffering:
                break;
            case MediaStatus.PlayerStateIdle:
                break;
            case MediaStatus.PlayerStatePaused:
                break;
            case MediaStatus.PlayerStatePlaying:
                break;
            case MediaStatus.PlayerStateUnknown:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The `OnStatusUpdated` method never gets called however, even if i call the `RequestStatus` method on the `RemoteMediaPlayer`.

Is there something I'm doing plain wrong or is something not working in Xamarin's bindings of `GooglePlayServices`?

Thanks in advance and I can provide clarification if needed!

Comment: For anyone who might come across this, I have reported the bug to Xamarin Support and they opened a bug report not too long ago. So I wasn't wrong.
Check it out here : [Bug Report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=28858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might come across this problem, be wary that you need to use this line :

```
CastClass.CastApi.SetMessageReceivedCallbacks(googleApiClient, mediaPlayer.Namespace, mediaPlayer);
```

where mediaPlayer is a RemoteMediaPlayer.

My problem was that I was using a custom implementation of the RemoteMediaPlayer and I overrided the Namespace get attribute to return a Namespace of my liking and that is okay with the documentation. See here :

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/Cast.CastApi.html#setMessageReceivedCallbacks(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.cast.Cast.MessageReceivedCallback)

(For some reason, there is a space (and I can't remove it as it would break the link) in the link and it's destroying the linking method for this website, but the link is correct if you copy and paste it... Sorry about that)

Even if my Namespace was of the format they want, it would not work. But it would not throw any exception.